# Can I access a variable in the child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access a variable in a window that I have opened.

Here is the parent window, it opens up a new window, sets a reference to the child window and then in another onclick event it attempts to retrieve a variable defined in the child window.

```
    var window1;

    //open a window
    $('#btnOpen').click(function () {
        window1 = window.open('openedwindow', 'window2');
    });

    //get child variable
    $('#btnGetChildVariable').click(function () {
        alert(window1.childVariable);
    });
```

here is the code in the child window

```
    var childVariable = 'My child';
```

Is this possible?  is window1.childVariable correct syntax, currently it just returns undefined (there is no unsafe javascript error and I've tried it to get at a control in the child window and I can access it).  Page 358 of Javascript the Definitive guide seems to suggest this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I went wrong was the following, I had defined

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

functions and my variables were defined within these functions.  That meant

```
var childVariable
```

was not defined in global scope but defined on the context of the function and therefore inaccessible outside of it (a closure I believe).

(it does work but please correct me if I've got any of this wrong)